Security of the files added to Samsung Secure folder
Suppose I enable the Samsung secure folder and add some files to it and protect it with a password (or even biometrics) on my A-series phone. How safe are the files in case my phones got stolen?
Obviously if they can unlock my phone phone they will get access to it.
What I am asking is that, if they try to remove the memory card from the motherboard and try to access the files, will they be able to access the files in my secure folder?

Not sure who secure the files are stored, but there is at least one company which claims to provide tools for data extraction: https://www.gmdsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/SamsungSecurefolder.pdf
